# Merging Facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Can I merge my Facebook page with another page with the same name but who's admin is not my friend and neither do I know him/her? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. The key part of this question is, "[The other page's] admin is not my friend and neither do I know him/her."

Notice that Facebook says, "Click the Merge duplicate Pages link. This link will only appear if ***you*** manage two Pages with similar names." Emphasis added.

The only way to merge pages is if you are the manager of both. There's nothing you can do (aside from reporting it to Facebook) about a page if you are not the manager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could merge the links as long as the names are same.  Content on the Page with more likes will remain unchanged, except for the addition of likes and check-ins added from the Page with fewer likes.

Check this out (official FB doc): https://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018/

> - Go to the Page with more likes. This will be the one you'll keep.
> - From the top of your Page, click Edit Page
> - Select Update Info
> - From the left sidebar, select Resources.
> - Click the Merge duplicate Pages link. This link will only appear if you manage two Pages with similar names.
> - A dialogue will show Pages you manage that qualify to be merged. Select the Page(s) you wish to merge. If you're merging Pages with a
>     location, they must have the same address information.

I [like this](http://www.thesocialanimal.com/social-media/how-to-combine-or-merge-two-facebook-pages-updated-2012) even better, it has screen shots

Comment: Without either of those links this answer has no information. Answers on Stack Exchange are expected to stand on their own and be useful to future readers. What happens when those links no longer work?

Comment: Good Comment. I wasn't thought from that angle... Thank You. I was thinking instead of copy and pate from the links point to the link of FaceBook as the question related to FB.

Comment: " This link will only appear if you manage two Pages with similar names."

He doesn't manage both the pages in question.